# problem with GD library

Tags: php, gd

When I use gd library in linux(my laptop or web host),it will show

> The image “http://rssreader.ir/testcode2/index.php” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

but when I use xamp on windows,I don't have this problem,
this message shown by every code,such as php.net gd library example 
where is my problem??
http://rssreader.ir/testcode2/index.php for e.g(this file in my web hosting)

Answer (score 0):

Do a File->Save As to save whatever your script is generating out to a file, then open that file in a text editor. Most likely there's some PHP errors/warnings being emitted by the script before the data, causing the browser to think it's a corrupted image.

Comment: I check it,but the file is true

<?php

$im = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);


imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 99, 99, 0xFFFFFF);


imagestring($im, 3, 40, 20, 'GD Library', 0xFFBA00);


header('Content-Type: image/gif');

imagegif($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>

Answer (score 0):

You can see the problem (on linux) with:

```
wget http://rssreader.ir/testcode2/index.php
cat index.php
```

I.e. there is a blank line before the "GIF87" characters. So look in your script for some stray whitespace outside the <?php ... ?> tags.